# Can .lk and .com of the same link be resolved to the same IP address?

Tags: ip-address

Eg: www.bogus.lk and www.bogus.com
I think that it can't be resolved to the same IP address as .lk link is used in Sri Lanka, while .com is used as a commercial one. So, I'm not exactly sure if I'm right

Answer (score 2):

The owners of `bogus.lk` choose what IP address to point `www.bogus.lk` to. The owners of `bogus.com` choose what IP address to point `www.bogus.com` to. If those two owners (or they're the same owner) choose the same IP address, then `www.bogus.lk` and `www.bogus.com` will resolve to the same IP address.

Comment: Yeah, many people own their .local country plus the .com - including me as a one-man-band. They're cheap & it saves you from being usurped by some dodgy domain trader.